# DataList and stored procedures

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, stored-procedures

My DataList isn't working. I inserted a table into its item template, and a label into each table cell.

In the ascx file I associated each label with: `<%# Eval("Field1") %>`, `<%# Eval("Field2") %>` .... etc. I have a stored procedure precisely returning a table with those fields (Field1, Field2, ...)

In the ascx.cs file, I specified the datasource for the Data List as being the table resulting from the execution of the stored procedure.

Did I do something wrong here?

I am expecting the Data List to be populated with the stored procedure results. I wrote a similar question earlier, but made it much simpler now, stressing where I think the error might stem from. Thanks a lot. The project runs but the data list doesn't display anything.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention this, so, I will try:

you should also call the DataList's DataBind method after its DataSource is set.

Comment: Thanks, Platon! Multumesc. I did the data binding already, so there must be something else. (The initial question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614687/data-list-populated-from-stored-procedure. It includes the data binding step).

Comment: @AnnaT, upload your code to, for example, DropBox and i will take a look shortly.

Comment: Platon, thank you very much, so kind of you!  I just discovered my own error: instead of copying the data list contained within the ascx file (as I did initially), one needs to drag and drop the entire ascx file that contains the data list, into where it is needed (in this case, into Catalog.aspx)! That was tricky for a newbie! Have a nice day!